# How to display Alertview with UILocalNotification instead of just Badge and make it stay unless users presses a button on UIalertView?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

In my app, I am trying to create an Alarm but the only problem is with ios6 UILocalnotification is been converted to badge instead of UIAlertView.
Here's the code i am using:

```
UILocalNotification * notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    notif.fireDate = date;
    notif.alertAction = @"Snooze";
    notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    notif.alertBody = @"Time to wake up";
    notif.soundName = @"client_song.mp3";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you don't get any choice about that. The user is allowed to specify (in the Settings app) that a local notification from your app should appear as an alert, or as a banner, or not appear at all - and you can't do anything about it. If you don't like that, don't use a local notification...

Comment: what is the alternative ??

Comment: It depends on what you are actually trying to do. What are you actually trying to do? Ask a new question about that. I believe I've answered the question you *did* ask.